# Finding concave hull for separated small clusters

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, computational-geometry, mesh, tetgenlink

Data :

```
 data3D = Import[file, "VertexData"];
 Graphics3D[Point[data3D]]
```

[image]

How to find concave polygon for separated small clusters.

Comment: Have you already explored the earlier question [Finding a Concave Hull](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8753/finding-a-concave-hull)?

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke That question came from the same poster

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The procedure I suggested for your other "concave hull" [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8753/finding-a-concave-hull) seems to work reasonably well here, simultaneously isolating the clusters and creating the surfaces.

```
Needs["TetGenLink`"];
{pts,tetrahedra}=TetGenDelaunay[data3D];
csr[{aa_,bb_,cc_,dd_}]:=With[{a=aa-dd,b=bb-dd,c=cc-dd},
Norm[a.a Cross[b,c]+b.b Cross[c,a]+c.c Cross[a,b]]/(2Norm[a.Cross[b,c]])];
radii=csr[pts[[#]]]&/@tetrahedra;
alphashape[rmax_]:=Pick[tetrahedra,radii,r_/;r<rmax];
faces[tetras_]:=Flatten[tetras/.{a_,b_,c_,d_}:>{{a,b,c},{a,b,d},{a,c,d},{b,c,d}},1];
externalfaces[faces_]:=Cases[Tally[Sort/@faces],{face_,1}:>face];

polys=externalfaces@faces@alphashape[1.8];

Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[],GraphicsComplex[pts,Polygon@polys]},Boxed->False]
```

[image]

### Cluster colouring

The clusters using this method are just sets of connected polygons. We can build a graph of these connections and use `ConnectedComponents` to find the individual clusters. This allows such things as colouring the clusters for easier visualisation.

```
clusters=ConnectedComponents@Graph@DeleteDuplicates[
Sort/@Flatten[UndirectedEdge@@@Subsets[#,{2}]&/@polys]];

clusteredpolys=GatherBy[polys,Position[clusters,First@#][[1,1]]&];

Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[],GraphicsComplex[pts,
{Hue[RandomReal[]],Polygon@#}&/@clusteredpolys]},Boxed->False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

As I said before, there really isn't such a thing as a concave hull.  What you want to do is plot your clusters here.

The first problem involves a machine vision problem known as *3D segmentation*.  Mathematica doesn't have any tools out of the box to do this, as far as I know.

One way is to *guess* how many "clusters" are in your data, although that's hard to say because it appear to be sort of fractal.  You should experiment with heuristics for doing this.

I guessed about 40 for your data:

```
Needs["TetGenLink`"];

data3D = Import["http://dl.dropbox.com/u/68983831/process02.vtk", 
   "VertexData"];

cls = FindClusters[data3D, 40];

Show[(Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None], 
      GraphicsComplex[#1, Polygon[TetGenConvexHull[#1]]]}] &) /@ cls]
```

[image: Clustered Data]

You might also try a different metric, although it makes clustering slower:

```
cls = FindClusters[data3D, 40, DistanceFunction -> ManhattanDistance];

Show[(Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None], 
      GraphicsComplex[#1, Polygon[TetGenConvexHull[#1]]]}] &) /@ cls]
```

[image: Clustered Using Manhattan Distance]

If you want something besides the convex hull for each cluster, you might try adapting an answer to [Finding a Concave Hull](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8753/finding-a-concave-hull).