# Merging of multiple 3D plots with Show using unified ColorBar

Tags: color, interpolation

This question follows my initial question that can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/109937/edit).

I created the following 4D plot (3 spacial coordinate + color) by interpolating points separately.

[image]

The full data (1.4Mb) can be imported via https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/327fed478fcf166c4403/raw/9f116770cf995f2232660061c202db7602b1836a/data.txt

The plot actually consists in the merge of 8 subplots, merged together with Show.

I still have a global color issue. Indeed the center part should actually be almost blue (low value) and the corner yellow (high value). Focusing on the lower half of the center part:

```
nf = Nearest[coo4[[All, {1, 2, 3}]] -> Rescale[coo4[[All, 4]]]];
colfun = ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", {minvalue, maxvalue}}]@
    First@nf[{#1, #2, #3}] &;
p2 = ListPlot3D[coo4[[All, 1 ;; 3]], 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, RegionMember[reg, {x, y}]], 
  ColorFunction -> colfun, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  MaxPlotPoints -> 100, BoxRatios -> Automatic, Mesh -> 10, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {minvalue, maxvalue}}, 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> True]]
```

For that section of the plot below, the value should be around 8. I have specify that the range for the ColorData should be between minval (here equal 1 to maxval, here equal 9).

[image]

It seems it takes the minvalue. If I remove {minval,maxval}

```
colfun = ColorData["TemperatureMap"]@First@nf[{#1, #2, #3}] &;
```

It gives me

[image]

which is not good because its scaled and therefore the different plot do not add up correctly with correct color for the final plot.

Any idea?

**Edit**

The code used to split the data and produce the full picture is the following. I was not so keen as to share it as I'm sure its very ugly, inefficient and long. Bear in mind that I started using Mathematica 3 days ago... I'm very happy to improve though.

```
coo1 = data.txt
maxvalue = Max[coo1[[All, 4]]]*1000;
minvalue  = Min[coo1[[All, 4]]]*1000;
coo2 = {coo1[[1, 1 ;; 4]]};
Do[If[ coo1[[i, 4]] > 0.0 && coo1[[i, 4]] < 0.00165 , {
    AppendTo[coo2, coo1[[i, 1 ;; 4]]]
    },], {i, 1, Length[coo1[[All, 1]]]}];
coo2 = Delete[coo2, 1];
coo21 = Select[coo2, #[[3]] < Max[coo1[[All, 3]]]/2 &];
coo22 = Select[coo2, #[[3]] > Max[coo1[[All, 3]]]/2 &];
coo3 = {coo1[[1, 1 ;; 4]]};
Do[If[ coo1[[i, 4]] > 0.00175 && coo1[[i, 4]] < 0.005, {
    AppendTo[coo3, coo1[[i, 1 ;; 4]]]
    },], {i, 1, Length[coo1[[All, 1]]]}];
coo3 = Delete[coo3, 1];
coo4 = Select[coo3, #[[3]] < Max[coo1[[All, 3]]]/2 + 0.03 &];
coo5 = Select[coo3, #[[3]] >= Max[coo1[[All, 3]]]/2 - 0.05 &];
coo6 =  Select[coo1, #[[4]] > 0.0082 & ];
coo7 = Select[coo6, #[[4]] < 0.0085 & ];
coo8 = Select[coo7, #[[1]]  < 0.25  &];
coo9 = Select[coo8, #[[2]]  < 0.25  &];
coo10 = Select[coo7, #[[1]]  < 0.25  &];
coo11 = Select[coo10, #[[2]]  > 0.25  &];
coo12 = Select[coo7, #[[1]]  > 0.5 &];
coo13 = Select[coo12, #[[2]]  < 1.0  &];
coo14 = Select[coo7, #[[1]]  > 0.5 &];
coo15 = Select[coo14, #[[2]]  > 1.0  &];

alphaShapes2D[points_, crit_] := 
  Module[{alphacriteria, del = Quiet@DelaunayMesh@points, tetras, 
    tetcoords, tetradii, selectExternalFaces}, 
   alphacriteria[tetrahedra_, radii_, rmax_] := 
    Pick[tetrahedra, UnitStep@Subtract[rmax, radii], 1];
   selectExternalFaces[facets_] := MeshRegion[points, facets];
   If[Head[del] === EmptyRegion, del, tetras = MeshCells[del, 2];
    tetcoords = MeshPrimitives[del, 2][[All, 1]];
    tetradii = Quiet@Thread[Circumsphere[tetcoords]][[All, 2]];
    selectExternalFaces@alphacriteria[tetras, tetradii, crit]]];

reg = alphaShapes2D[DeleteDuplicates@coo21[[All, ;; 2]], .2]
nf = Nearest[coo21[[All, {1, 2, 3}]] -> Rescale[coo21[[All, 4]]]];
colfun = ColorData[{"TemperatureMap"]@
    First@nf[{#1, #2, #3}] &;
p1 = ListPlot3D[coo21[[All, 1 ;; 3]], 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, RegionMember[reg, {x, y}]], 
  ColorFunction -> colfun, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  MaxPlotPoints -> 100, BoxRatios -> Automatic, Mesh -> 10]
reg = alphaShapes2D[DeleteDuplicates@coo22[[All, ;; 2]], .2]
nf = Nearest[coo22[[All, {1, 2, 3}]] -> Rescale[coo22[[All, 4]]]];
colfun = ColorData["TemperatureMap"]@First@nf[{#1, #2, #3}] &;
p11 = ListPlot3D[coo22[[All, 1 ;; 3]], 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, RegionMember[reg, {x, y}]], 
  ColorFunction -> colfun, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  MaxPlotPoints -> 100, BoxRatios -> Automatic, Mesh -> 10]
reg = alphaShapes2D[DeleteDuplicates@coo4[[All, ;; 2]], .2]
nf = Nearest[coo4[[All, {1, 2, 3}]] -> Rescale[coo4[[All, 4]]]];
colfun = ColorData["TemperatureMap"]@First@nf[{#1, #2, #3}] &;
p2 = ListPlot3D[coo4[[All, 1 ;; 3]], 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, RegionMember[reg, {x, y}]], 
  ColorFunction -> colfun, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  MaxPlotPoints -> 100, BoxRatios -> Automatic, Mesh -> 10, 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> True]]
reg = alphaShapes2D[DeleteDuplicates@coo5[[All, ;; 2]], .15]
nf = Nearest[coo5[[All, {1, 2, 3}]] -> Rescale[coo5[[All, 4]]]];
colfun = ColorData["TemperatureMap"]@First@nf[{#1, #2, #3}] &;
p3 = ListPlot3D[coo5[[All, 1 ;; 3]], 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, RegionMember[reg, {x, y}]], 
  ColorFunction -> colfun, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  MaxPlotPoints -> 100, BoxRatios -> Automatic, Mesh -> 10]

nf = Nearest[coo7[[All, {1, 2, 3}]] -> Rescale[coo7[[All, 4]]]];
colfun = ColorData["TemperatureMap"]@
    First@nf[{#1, #2, #3}] &;
p4 = ListSurfacePlot3D[coo9[[All, 1 ;; 3]], ColorFunction -> colfun, 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, MaxPlotPoints -> 10, Mesh -> 5];
p5 = ListSurfacePlot3D[coo11[[All, 1 ;; 3]], ColorFunction -> colfun, 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, MaxPlotPoints -> 10, Mesh -> 5];
p6 = ListSurfacePlot3D[coo13[[All, 1 ;; 3]], ColorFunction -> colfun, 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, MaxPlotPoints -> 10, Mesh -> 5];
p7 = ListSurfacePlot3D[coo15[[All, 1 ;; 3]], ColorFunction -> colfun, 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, MaxPlotPoints -> 10, Mesh -> 5];
Show[{p1, p11, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: How is the data split up into 8 regions?  The linked data file has 29,764 elements.  Which part of it is `coo4`?  I'm interested to reproduce [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Pp1nF.jpg) image but I don't see how.

Comment: @JasonB, sure done.  I was not so keen as to share it as I'm sure its very ugly, inefficient and long.

Comment: why do you use different color schemes for the different parts? I see SunsetColors, Rainbow, and TemperatureMap there.

Comment: Some trial and errors I forgot to remove. Should be "TemperatureMap" everywhere. I've updated the question.

Comment: no time right now to do it proper, so this includes only 4 of the regions, but what do you think of it as a starting point:  `reg = alphaShapes2D[DeleteDuplicates@coo21[[All, ;; 2]], .2];

rf = Function[{x, y, z}, RegionMember[reg, {x, y}]];
ListPlot3D[{coo21, coo22, coo4, coo5}[[All, All, ;; 3]], 
 RegionFunction -> rf, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
 MaxPlotPoints -> 100, BoxRatios -> Automatic, Mesh -> 10]`

Comment: Your proposition gives the color according to the height along the z axes whereas I would like to have the color depending on the 4th argument of my dataset.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that on my bikeride home, but it's a step in the right direction.

Comment: Maybe but I'm not sure since it seems difficult to go around the nearest neighbour colour interpolation that should be different for each plot.

Comment: so you want these all to be plotted with a unified color scheme.  Looking at the data, the regions in the corner have much higher values than the shapes in the middle, about 8 times as high.  So the plot I end up with basically has the corner parts all in red and the tubes in the middle mostly in blue - is this right?

Comment: It is totally right ! However the idea is not to have uniform color (red for tube and blue for middle) because the local variation of blue and red are important. Can you share the plot you ended up with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So keeping all your code up until just after the definition for `alphashapes2D`,

```
minmax = MinMax@{coo9, coo11, coo13, coo15, coo21, coo22, coo4, 
     coo5}[[All, All, 4]];
tubePlot[data_] := Module[{nf, colfun, reg},
   reg = alphaShapes2D[data[[All, ;; 2]] // DeleteDuplicates, .2];
   nf = Nearest[
     data[[All, ;; 3]] -> Rescale[data[[All, 4]], minmax]];
   colfun = ColorData["TemperatureMap"]@First@nf[{#1, #2, #3}] &;
   ListPlot3D[data[[All, ;; 3]],
    ColorFunction -> colfun,
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
    RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, RegionMember[reg, {x, y}]],
    MaxPlotPoints -> 100,
    Mesh -> 10
    ]
   ];
cornerPlot[data_] := Module[{nf, colfun},
   nf = Nearest[
     data[[All, ;; 3]] -> Rescale[data[[All, 4]], minmax]];
   colfun = ColorData["TemperatureMap"]@First@nf[{#1, #2, #3}] &;
   ListSurfacePlot3D[data[[All, ;; 3]],
    ColorFunction -> colfun,
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
    MaxPlotPoints -> 5,
    Mesh -> 5
    ]
   ];
plotrange = 
  MinMax /@ 
   Transpose[
    Join[coo9, coo11, coo13, coo15, coo21, coo22, coo4, 
      coo5][[All, ;; 3]]];
Show[tubePlot /@ {coo21, coo22, coo4, coo5},
 cornerPlot /@ {coo9, coo11, coo13, coo15},
 PlotRange -> plotrange,
 BoxRatios -> Automatic,
 ImageSize -> 600
 ]
```

[image]

Aside from the differences in how I wrote the plotting functions (I hate to write the same things over and over again, so I make functions to do it for me), the main difference is that when I rescale the fourth data points, I use the second argument to `Rescale`.  Every data point is rescaled on the same scale for all the different plots.

Comment: Thank you !  The crucial bit was "Rescale[data[[All, 4]], minmax]];" Super !